# python bs4 | Как осуществить поиск по zip списку

Tags: python, bs4

```
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://XXXXXXXXX'
response = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
all_TD = bs.find_all('td', class_='row3 over') # весь TD
all_a = bs.find_all('a', class_='last-post-icon') # весь а тег

for item, item2 in zip(all_a, all_TD):
    item2 = item2.get_text(':')
    name = item2
    item_url = item.get("href")
    href = item_url
    print(f'{name} https://XXXXXX{href}')
```

Формат вывода:

1. Название_темы:Дата:Ник:Ссылка
2. ...
3. ...

Как осуществить поиск по определенному нику, чтобы отфильтровать уже готовый список?

Comment: Без примера данных, которые парсите, вам сложно будет помочь. Надо смотреть что сидит в тегах где записан nickname, возможно там есть какой-то class или id, к которому можно приципиться.